# C++ How to generate a random Path

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to write a function that can generate a random path for a given 2D array of points (x, y).

Now the path has a few requirements I'd like it to meet in order for it to be valid. 
The path **cannot**:

- ...be a straight line from point **A** to **B**.
- ...go back on itself but can go backwards (*demonstrated below*).
- ...run parallel/along itself.

I also want to make sure the path starts from the left and ends on the right to hopefully keep it simple.

So I'm looking for something that would do:

```
.........     | .........     | ########.
.........     | .........     | .......#.
##....### end | ....####.     | ...#####.
.######..     | #####..#.     | ...#.....
.........     | .......## end | ...###### end
```

But I don't know where to start and there's vary little information available that does something similar to this.

I could go the A* rout but that seems overkill and from what I know about A* (*vary little*) I'd need to create "fake" obstacles. Anyway before I go on a rant, can anyone help me?

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: It seems you have to make use of an algorithm which helps you determine whether certain vertices are isolated from the destination nodes at certain time.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: You could figure out which moves are valid for the current point, then randomly select one of those moves. You would need to do this recursively so that the algorithm could "back-track" to the previous point if the current point has no valid moves. The algorithm is complete when you reach the destination point.

Comment: @user3046336, in your 2nd and 3rd examples, why wouldn't you just go from `A` all the way to the right and then all the way down to `B`. This would still satisfy your 3 conditions, plus the 4th one of 'left-to-right'. Why do you have to make extra loops? Please clarify

Comment: @InnocentBystander, The question states the path is generated *randomly*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following description and code snippet should give you enough information to solve the problem without providing an exact solution. Note: the following does not satisfy all of your criteria (e.g., preventing a straight line solution) but any missing pieces should be easy to fill in.

---

1. Create the grid
2. Generate random starting cell
3. Generate random ending cell that is different than the starting cell
4. Walk from the starting cell to the ending cell

   1. Mark each position as being 'visited'
   2. Determine the valid moves from this position

      1. At least 1 valid move: add this position position to the 'solution path' and update this position to be one of the valid moves
      2. No valid moves: update this position to be the position most recently added to the solution path (i.e., backup) and remove the position most recently
         added to the solution path

         - Note if the 'solution path' is empty restart again at step 4
5. Reset the grid back to its original state
6. Traverse the solution path and mark each cell as 'visited'
7. Print grid

---

```
// Step 1
Grid grid(10, 10);

// Step 2
Cell start = grid.generateRandomCell();

// Step 3
Cell end = start;
while (end == start)
{
    end = grid.generateRandomCell();
}

std::vector<Cell> solutionPath;

// Step 4
Cell pos = start;
while (pos != end)
{
    // Step 4.1
    grid.setValue(pos, '#');

    // Step 4.2
    std::vector<Cell> possibleMoves = getPossibleMoves(grid, pos);
    if (!possibleMoves.empty())
    {
        // Step 4.2.1
        solutionPath.push_back(pos);
        pos = possibleMoves[rand() % possibleMoves.size()];
    }
    else
    {
        // Step 4.2.2
        if (!solutionPath.empty())
        {
            pos = solutionPath.back();
            solutionPath.erase(--solutionPath.end());
        }
        else
        {
            pos = start;
            grid.reset();
        }
    }
}

// Step 5
grid.reset();

// Step 6
for (size_t i = 1; i < solutionPath.size(); ++i)
{
    grid.setValue(solutionPath[i], 'A' + ((i - 1) % 26));
}
grid.setValue(start, '@');
grid.setValue(end, '!');

// Step 7
std::cout << grid << "\n";
```

Comment: This solution won't work every time, you go back one move when you have no  valid moves. So what happens if you get into a situation where your moves have created a spiral, around the side of the board. This means you have one valid move to the centre, you then move. You now have no valid moves and so you back track 1 step. You then move again into the centre creating an infinite loop. Recursion is better suited for this problem. Just saying.

Comment: This does not loop infinitely, the visited cells are not 'unmarked' so going back one-step (i.e., same effect as returning from a recursive function call) allows the remaining moves to be considered and if there are none it will continue to back up (i.e., it will never return to a cell it has already visited, except as part of backing up)

Comment: "Recursion is better suited", my solution is recursive in nature (the use of a stack is a strong hint). Here's is a SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration) regarding using iteration instead of a recursive solution.

Comment: Do you know what recursion is? Not being rude, but your solution has 0 recursion

Comment: Yes, I know that a function which calls itself is recursion. I said my solution is _recursive in nature_ (i.e., instead of pushing arguments onto an application stack via a function call it uses a stack data structure to achieve the same affect).

Answer (score 1):

You can just try things one square at a time until you find a solution:

- do

  - create an array e.g. `bool points[Num_Rows][Num_Columns] = { false };`, tracking where you've been
  - initialise `std::pair<int,int> cursor { rand() % Num_Rows, 0 };`, tracking where you are
    repeat

    - work out which directions your cursor can move in without leaving the board or breaking your rules
    - if there are none, you're bust: go back to "do" above
    - pick one, recording that you've moved there by setting the related `points[]` element

      - if you're cursor's in the right-hand column, you're done, **break** from the loop